Certain custom fonts not appearing with Tailwind CSS
I'm trying to make my first app using React Native and Tailwind. I imported the Rajdhani font family to use in this app, but for some reason only Rajdhani Bold actually shows up in the Expo preview on my IOS device that I'm testing on.
this is my index.js file:
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { Text, View} from "react-native";
import { Link } from "expo-router";

export default function App(){
    return(
        <View className="flex-1 items-center justify-center bg-white">
            <Text className="text-3xl font-rSemiBold">Test test</Text>
            <StatusBar style="auto" />
            <Link href="/sign-in" style={{color: 'blue'}}>Proceed to Login</Link>
        </View>
    );
}

This is my tailwind.config.js:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./app/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: '#D0E358'
      }
    },
    fontFamily: {
      rRegular: ["Rajdhani-Regular", "sans-serif"],
      rBold: ["Rajdhani-Bold", "sans-serif"],
      rSemiBold: ["Rajdhani-SemiBold", "sans-serif"],
      rLight: ["Rajdhani-Light", "sans-serif"],
      rMedium: ["Rajdhani-Medium", "sans-serif"]
    }
    
  },
  plugins: [],
}

and I've also attached an image of my folder structure:screenshot
if I replace rSemiBold with rBold, then it will work as intended, but any of the other members of the font family do not. I've tried messing around with the config file by adding single quotes around my custom font names or inside the double quotes but nothing has worked. The file names are correct too and I checked the ttf files to make sure there was nothing wrong with them

You need to import the fonts using the useFonts hook from expo in your _layout.tsx file, perhaps you can share a snapshot of your layout file
